# SQL Server 2014 Express, Standard Evaluation and limiting CPU and RAM

Tags: sql-server

Does Sqlserver 2014 sp1 evaluation edition limit Ram and cpu usage? What if Standard is a 2nd instance and the first instance is Sql Server 2014 Express. Will Express cause the evaluation Standard Edition to have same limits? My performance indicates such. I can't get an answer from my reseller or Microsoft in a timely manner.  I am going to remove Express tonight and see if Standards' performance increases significantly.

Comment: You really think Express changes Standard?

Comment: No Frisbee, I don't, but I've been working this problem with the 3rd party software vendor whose code is running much slower now than it did on a much more inferior bare metal box than it does on the much newer, more powerful VM.  My suspicions lie with the vendor's code.  The hard part is that since this has been going on for a month, with varying things tried (including vendor remoted in and looking at things), that a lot of changes have been made, including the vendor upgrading their code.

Comment: I have now removed Express (not so easy when you have standard installed too).  I had to disable the the instances associated with the Express installation.  Application is still slow on some workstations when doing the same operation whereas it wasn't before we upgraded).   It appears both Express and SP1 share a code base?  I don't know how to uninstall Express only using Windows Features and Programs.  It looks like it would uninstall both.  Maybe that is my next step?  Then, reinstall SP1?  I wish I knew what MS does when they install stuff (what registry entries and files are installed?)

Comment: Just shut down the service

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as Standard Evaluation Edition. SQL Server Evaluation is an Enterprise SKU and has no enforced resource limitations.

Your SQLEXPRESS instance will compete with the Evaluation instance for resources. This may affect the overall performance, but won't enforce the same limitations you have in Express on the Evaluation instance.

Comment: I didn't notice any degradation to Express after installing Standard, but I agree, there has to be more load with Standard installed too.  I think the problem is with the 3rd party vendor code, and am concentrating efforts there now.  Thanks.